# Does Outlook 2010 disable add ins for slow start?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I know that Outlook 2013 and 2016 disable add ins if start time is more than 1 second. Does Outlook 2010 have the same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled was introduced with Outlook 2013. See [New in Outlook for developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx) for more information.